# How to manage multi git repository maven project?

Tags: git, maven

We have several projects, each in different git repository, that depends on each other via maven dependencies.
Developing in such environment is pure hell - suppose i'm working in two projects, A and B, where B have A as maven dependency. I currently need to:

1. Change A.
2. Make sure that B declares most recent version of A.
3. Install and publish locally A through maven.
4. Only now you can see these changes in B.
5. Change A again and repeat all over.

Maybe there is way to ease this process a little? Like forcing maven to build and use local projects, and not cached ones.

Comment: Same git repository much easier to handle from. Maven perspective as well as from git perspective. Single commit for a change which influences different areas.

Answer (score 0):

The way to ease it is to put them into the same git repository and use a Maven multi module project.

Comment: Yeah, i know about this possibility, but i'm mainly looking for a way to keep current structure.

Comment: Why? What is the advantage of the structure? It makes things only more complicated than needed...from different point of views..